# Hey, can anyone explain me this line of code?

Tags: javascript, angular

```
<button [disabled] = " username === '' "  (click)=" username = '' ">Reset User</button>
```

In my `app.component.ts` I only have this variable:
`"username = '';"`

Comment: Hi, this line will render a button that will be disabled if the `username` property is equal to an empty string. Also, the username will be cleared when you click the button (so, it will be disabled).

Comment: The code you've shown will always display a disabled button unless the `username` variable is assigned a truthy value elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

The attribute disabled of the `<button>` is set, if the username is empty '', when you click on the button it sets the var username to empty !

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you are disabling your button when it clicks.

```
[disabled] = " username === '' " // if username is empty it going to return true

(click)=" username = '' " // set it to empty when clicks
```

Answer (score 0):

when you will click on this button, username is assigned an empty string and when username is an empty string button will be disabled, means nothing is going to happen when you will click on the button.